# Oracle package variable not get set from sp parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Trying to set a local variable to parameter value that is passed to Oracle stored procedure However i am getting nottihgn..what am i doing wrong. When I test the package v_param is empty.
I am passing a long text

```
create or replace package MA_MAIN_SP_TESTCLOB IS
   v_param clob;
   procedure RUNALL( iOffice clob);
end MA_MAIN_SP_TESTCLOB;


create or replace package body MA_MAIN_SP_TESTCLOB IS
    procedure RUNALL(iOffice clob) IS
    BEGIN 
         v_param := iOffice; 

        --dbms_output.put_line('Parmeters are ' || v_param);
        insert into ICCMSDW_CR.OfficeHolder(POFFICE)
        values(v_param);
    END RUNALL;
END MA_MAIN_SP_TESTCLOB;
```

Comment: and how are you calling MA_MAIN_SP_TESTCLOB?

Comment: Executing package from PL/sql developer window, test and pass comma sperated value

Comment: which version of oracle ?

Comment: check this URL https://forums.oracle.com/thread/321069

Comment: Can you include the code that uses the variable?  That package should work, maybe there's an issue with how you are retrieving the variable.  For example, are you retrieving it from the same session that set it?

Comment: no magic. Create store proc do the same thing, when I pass CLOB from the PL/SQL developer, DBMS output is empty.. 
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MYPROC" (p_clob CLOB) is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(p_clob);
end myproc;

Comment: Same session, just exec sp dont work as well, above sp receives CLOB
begin
 ma_main_sp_testclob.runall(poffices => :poffices);
end;
variable poffices,Type CLOB, Value 'TEST1,TEST2,TEST3' 
dbms_output is empty

Comment: Yup working, I quess the session issue was the prob..thanks mate